# Поиск подстроки в строке с начала

Tags: javascript

Есть список городов.

При вводе данных в строку в списке должны остаться города, которые начинаются с вводимого значения. То есть если я пишу "аб" то у меня должен остаться только **абакан**, но не **набережные челны**

- Балаково
- Абакан
- Архангельск
- Набережные челны

Попробовал вот так, но ищет `currentdata` по всей строке

```
str.toLowerCase().indexOf(currentdata.toLowerCase());
```

вот моя функция:

```js
$('#test').keyup(function() {
  currenVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('ul.content>li').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(currenVal) > -1) {
      $(el).removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $(el).addClass('hidden');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
li.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">
<ul class="content">
  <li>Абакан</li>
  <li>Ангарск</li>
  <li>Армавир</li>
  <li>Архангельск</li>
  <li>Астрахань</li>
  <li>Балаково</li>
  <li>Балашиха</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добавьте еще тогда html-разметку, чтобы можно было полностью воспроизвести ваш код и внести в него необходимые правки

Comment: А если у ваш код работает, то вам надо заменить `>-1` на `==0`, так как вы ищете любое вхождение, а не первое

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin спасибо то что надо, читал, не увидел что так можно, пример кода вверху передал, если поменять на ==0 то работает как надо

Comment: Для красоты можно использовать функцию toogleClass: `$(el).toggleClass('hidden', $(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(currenVal) !== 0);` . Пропадет необходимость в ветвлении.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('#test').keyup(function() {
  currenVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('ul.content>li').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(currenVal) == 0) {
      $(el).removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $(el).addClass('hidden');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
li.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">
<ul class="content">
  <li>Абакан</li>
  <li>Ангарск</li>
  <li>Армавир</li>
  <li>Архангельск</li>
  <li>Астрахань</li>
  <li>Балаково</li>
  <li>Балашиха</li>
  <li>Набережные чалны</li>
</ul>
```

`indexOf` возвращает индекс первого вхождения, если вам надо, чтобы поиск осуществлялся в начале строки, то над делать проверку на то равен ли `indexOf` нулю

```js
let array = [
  'Балаково',
  'Абакан',
  'Архангельск',
  'Набережные челны'
]

let filter = 'аб';

//Поиск вхождения только в начале
console.log(array.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) == 0));

//Поиск по любому вхождению
console.log(array.filter(x => x.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0));
```

Comment: список городов это маркированный сиписок а не массив. конечно я могу собрать массив, из маркированного списка, потом воспользоваться вашей функцией, но потом мне снова нужно будет парсить итоговый массив и скрывать элементы маркированного списка которого нет в этом массиве. Но я использую функцию each, внутри которой и скрываю элементы не соответствующие вводимым данным, хотелось бы как то изменить именно сам метод поиска

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов а какая разница массив у вас или "список"? Речь ведь в ответе о том, что вы неправильно используете метод `indexOf` из `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем такие сложности? Используйте функцию `str.startsWith()`.

Нужно всего-то заменить

```
($(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(currenVal) > -1)
```

на

```
($(el).text().toLowerCase().startsWith(currenVal))
```

Comment: Сокращение кода на несколько символов и получение при этом проблем в старых (причем не таких уж и старых - тот же IE11, например) браузерах - действительно ли это проще?

Comment: @Regent Про сокращение кода я ничего не говорил, а ограниченная поддержка - недостаток, согласен.